# GCP Billing report does not contain resource id

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I generated a billing report(export to csv) for GCP but not able to map billing entry to the resource as there is no resource id present.  How am I supposed to know the cost for the individual resource

AWS gives to option to explicitly include the resource id.

Any Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use labels to do it. Have a look at the documentation [Creating and managing labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels):

> A label is a key-value pair that helps you organize your Google Cloud
> instances. You can attach a label to each resource, then filter the
> resources based on their labels. **Information about labels is forwarded
> to the billing system, so you can break down your billing charges by
> label.**

You can create labels by using [Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels), [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#using_console) or `gcloud` command (here an [example](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/add-labels) for GCE VM instances).

[Services currently supporting labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels#label_support):

> - BigQuery
> - Cloud Bigtable
> - Dataflow
> - Dataproc
> - Cloud Deployment Manager
> - Cloud Functions
> - Cloud Healthcare API
> - Cloud Key Management Service
> - Pub/Sub
> - Cloud Spanner
> - Cloud SQL
> - Cloud Storage
> - Compute Engine
> - Google Kubernetes Engine
> - Cloud Run (fully managed)
> - Networking
> - Resource Manager (projects only)
> - App Engine (both Flexible and Standard environments)

More information about using labels you can find at the documentation [View your billing reports and cost trends](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports), [View and download the cost details of your invoice or statement](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/cost-table) and [Export Cloud Billing data to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery)

Answer (score 0):

Thank your Response.

I did try it with labels, but in CSV report there is a column for Project Labels only. I exported the same report in Big query and i was able to see columns for tree types of labels project labels, system labels, and labels. The labels which I was setting in VMs I could see them in the third column.

Not sure what are project labels